# The browser freezes and html page is non-interactive

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I am new to using CEF Sharp. So I went to the [github.io](http://cefsharp.github.io) page which pointed me to this [setup tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1058700/Embedding-Chrome-in-your-Csharp-App-using-CefSharp)

Having setup my project using Nuget, which installed CEF 47. I ran the project (which simply opened Chromium browser in a WinForm with http://www.google.com). The browser opened up fine but then I could not interact with the page. I could not select the text box or click on the html buttons. When I tried to resize the browser, the app froze and I had to stop the debugger to get out of it.

Am I missing something?

Here is the code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;

namespace CEFRetest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitBrowser();
        }

        public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
        public void InitBrowser()
        {
            Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.google.com");
            this.Controls.Add(browser);
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing that I noticed, is that the dlls (`libcef.dll, icudtl.dat, CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.exe, CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.Core.dll`) are not in my `bin/Debug` directory when I install `CefSharp.WinForm` using `Nuget Package Manager`. I only references that are added from Nuget are `CefSharp, CefSharp.Core and CefSharp.WinForms`.

Could that be a problem?

**UPDATE**

Ok so it seems I have the required dlls and files but they are in `bin\x64\Debug`.

Comment: The official example is https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample, take it for a spin, compare it to the code you ended up with.

Comment: I have just followed the setup tutorial and this works correctly. You must have done something different. Why not show us the Source code, it is only a few lines

Comment: Also, I am using a VS 2013 on Win 8 machine

Comment: @amaitland I cloned the `CefSharp.MinimalExample` and ran the code but I got this error `Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.`

Comment: Try rebuild a few times. Make sure you've got all the latest updates for `Visual Studio` and `Nuget`. Error message usually indicates that some of the dependencies failed to download or that `VC++ 2013` isn't installed, which is unlikely as you have `Visual Studio` installed. Check the `bin` folder, make sure all the dependencies are present as per https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-%28Redistribution%29

Comment: Ok so for some reason my VS 2012 was not working properly. I had to uninstall VS 2012 and install VS 2013 it and not it works fine.